# get current length of text as typed in UITextField

Tags: objective-c

I am using UITextFieldDelegate but the method I am using:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Only get's fired before the text is edited.  I need the length of the text as it stands after they type a letter.  Using the method above I am always 1 letter behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the new length:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger length = [[textField text] length] - range.length + string.length;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is connect a method to your UITextField for the "Editing Changed" - event. Then every time the user enters (or removes) a letter that method will be instantaneously called.
Hope it helps!